# Echo show_count of categories separately without using wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

[image]I want to show the count of a particular category, that means how many posts does a particular category have?

I want the number as same as in the picture, but they are echoing like:

> Bathroom Scales (1)
>   uncategorized (3)

My code is:

```
echo wp_list_categories(array(
'show_count' => 'true',
'title_li' => '',
'style' => ''));
```

Is there any other way to do this counting thing separately?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `get_categories()`. You'll get back an array of term objects:

```
array(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] =>
        [name] =>
        [slug] =>
        [term_group] =>
        [term_taxonomy_id] =>
        [taxonomy] =>
        [description] =>
        [parent] =>
        [count] =>
        [filter] =>
    )
)
```

You can process this with `wp_list_pluck` to turn it into an associative array, so for example:

```
 $cat_counts = wp_list_pluck( get_categories(), 'count', 'name' );
```

This will return an array like:

```
array(
    'Geography' => 5,
    'Maths' => 7,
    'English' => 3,
)
```

For other taxonomies use `get_terms()` instead.  `get_categories()` is really not much more than a wrapper for `get_terms()`.

To show these like the picture you've added to your question, just loop over the array.

```
echo '<dl>';
// use whichever HTML structure you feel is appropriate

foreach ( $cat_counts as $name => $count ) {
    echo '<dt>' . $name . '</dt>';
    echo '<dd>' . sprintf( "%02d", $count ) . '</dd>';
    // use sprintf to specify 2 decimal characters with leading zero if necessary
}

echo '</dl>';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it helped, but i have a more problem , i want to echoing the categories using while loop `while( have_posts()) : the_post();` and now from your code the count is not echoing with particular category, i used `implode(' ', $cat_counts)` to convert it into string.Can you help with this, see the picture in my question i want same as that. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use The Loop `while( have_posts()) : the_post();` unless you have queried WP for Posts.  Just use standard PHP loop constructs.  I'll expand my answer.

Comment: `<?php while( have_posts()) : the_post();?>`

Comment: Updated the question. `Implode` won't keep both the index and value of the array.

Comment: Thank you so very much, you're great.I appreciate you're effort. I know it will be more silly to ask one more question regarding this same question but as i am new to programming, the loop you said is echoing all the categories in all post , i want to echo post with it's own categories

Comment: You just want to list all the categories that a post is in when you display that post? If you ask that as another question to keep the site format tidy then I'll answer there. By all means accept this answer if it has helped too!

Comment: hello @Andy, i am back with this topic and i asked more question on the same topic(i want to display the category of a particular post).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category/), it returns an object, with the for you relevant property `category_count`.